# Does Azure Logic Apps Filter Array action supports multiple conditions?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am filtering on an array of addresses. A type attribute determines the address category (POSTAL,RES,WORK etc). I need to filter only the POSTAL and RES address from this array.

I tried to use the filer array action , but it can take only one filter condition.

Can it be edited in the code view to achieve multiple filter conditions ? If yes, what is correct syntax for it.

```
{
    "Name": "Douglas Adams",
    "Address": [
        {
            "Type": "POSTALS",
            "street_address": "42",
            "city": "Milky Way",
            "state": "HI"
        },
        {
            "Type": "RES",
            "street_address": "1618",
            "city": "Golden ratio",
            "state": "MA"
        },
        {
            "Type": "BILLING",
            "street_address": "1618",
            "city": "Golden ratio",
            "state": "MA"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Azure Filter array condition]

Comment: Tried a few variations on the where clause (as referred in the comment to your post), but not with any success.

Answer (score 8):

> Can it be edited in the code view to achieve multiple filter conditions ?

In short, **Yes**. Logic Apps now supports multiple rules in a condition block. Here is a  [issue](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/13845105-allows-multiple-rules-within-a-condition-block) you could refer to.

Because I do not know the action above your Filter array, so I will give you a similar syntax (e.g. http body is equal 'bbb' and http headers is equal 'aaa') as below:

```
@and(equals(triggerOutputs()['headers'],'aaa'), equals(triggerBody(),'bbb'))
```

You could modify to your situation and fill into `edit in basic mode` in Filter array.

For more details, you could refer to this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ea39f888-c60c-41db-9898-bffbf2f6f599/multiple-logical-operators-in-logic-app?forum=azurelogicapps).

Comment: Thanks Joey
As I interpret this, it is possible to give compound conditionals in the Condition Block.

I am referring to a Filter block.

Code behind for Condition and Filter looks quite different.

For the filter , it looks more like a SQL clause.

'
"Filter_Errors": {
"type": "Query",
"inputs": {
"from": "@result('ProcessMessage')",
"where": "@equals(item()['status'], 'Failed')"
}
'

Is it supported to supply multiple conditions in a where clause for a Filter Action ?

Comment: I was able to use this in a filter array and worked. Thanks @JoeyCai

Comment: Glad to helps you:)